# Is calling an instance method and passing a property of that same object to it a code smell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a class that will return an NSPredicate. I have written code like this:

```
constructedPredicate = [self predicateForSection:self.systemsSection];
```

I am wanting to keep the logic central to one method (other parts of the class call this same method and pass different properties), but my intuition is that it is a code smell / bad practice to call a method and pass a property into it. Is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Nah;  that is fine.

The property is a simple accessor.  It just grabs the current state from the object.

The method computes a value based on a parameter.

This is exactly the delineation in functionality that properties were designed to address.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see anything wrong with that at all.